# Good quality C# code

Tags: c#

Where can I find samples of C# code written by top programmers, for learning?

Answer (score 12):

There's [a collection of Jon Skeet's C# and .NET articles and links](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/) online, and you can't go wrong with Jon Skeet's code.  It's not too code-heavy, but his insights in the other *aspects* of C# are invaluable - especially if you are really interested in really *learning* the language, not just learning the syntax.

Comment: Link doesn't appear to work anymore, new link: https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/

Answer (score 5):

Scott Hanselman has a great series, "[The Weekly Source Code](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CategoryView.aspx?category=Source+Code)" which are well worth a read.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at the [Mono project source code](https://github.com/mono/mono).

Answer (score 2):

I would check out [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/).

Comment: There's a lot of code on CodePlex, but how much of it is good? ;)

Comment: Well, you need to choose projects carefully then...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the many suggestions on source code, I would also recommend the book [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) as it has numerous useful dos and don'ts, which I find very helpful. There's also a section on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx) with some of the same topics.

Answer (score 1):

[CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com) has a lot of useful samples, and they're very good as learning tools because they're often not very complete or full-featured, so you still have to do some thinking and working to get them to do what you want them to do.

Answer (score 1):

Half the battle of creating good quality code in any language is using it smartly. [Software design patterns and practices like those](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/default.aspx) published by Microsoft go a long way toward that. There are many books on the subject too.

The MSDN documentation itself is chock full of code samples freely available from Microsoft, direct from the makers of C#/.NET. There's a good chance of finding a lot of quality code from the software company itself, even if contained in simple examples. There are countless samples for everything and always little things no matter how much you know. Knowing the nuances of C# topics goes a long way too.

Also use insights gained from across a variety of books. Not every book contains everything, so expand your ability to make good coding decisions by knowing a lot from other people's experiences.

Rub elbows with a variety of programmers at user groups or even in courses, those outside the familiar culture of your workplace.

Start an open-source project or contribute to one of interest to be around more code.

Answer (score 1):

[Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/index.html) is a great project that was originally open source. Due to abuse the author has closed the source, but an older version of the source is available through a [third party](http://www.afterdawn.com/software/source_codes/paint.net.cfm).

Comment: People were building their own versions and selling them.

Answer (score 1):

People often point to coding guidelines as the best way to write good code. Actually, I think that philosophically speaking, writing good code starts with oneself. Of course coding guidelines are important, but actually, there are conflicting guidelines and philosophies out there that make it very difficult to follow a set of coding rules religiously. For example, having multiple return statements in a single function increases cyclomatic complexity in code, but, without doing this, nesting is often increased. So, there's a decision to be made about how to restructure the code.

The most important thing is attitude. A good coder always asks questions, and listens to others. They may not always agree, but they are always looking for better ways to sharpen their tool set, and expand upon what they know.

I know this is abstract, but programming is all about abstraction.

A good way to get started is to take some code from your team, apply all of the code rules in Visual Studio to the code, and discuss how and why each of the rules could or should be implemented. Some rules will contradict other rules, so you must decide which are useful and which are not. It is also important to take note of the effects of each code rule over the long term, and to ask continuously ask the question: has this increased code quality? Or, is this just fiddling?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following book greatly useful when I started programming:

Code Complete: A Practical Handbook of Software Construction (Steve McConnell - Microsoft Press)

[http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670)